# Cannot set bold e-mail body text using `ShareCompat.IntentBuilder`

Tags: android, android-support-library

I'm trying to share text via email application using `ShareCompat.IntentBuilder`, but HTML tags (e.g. `<b>Some text</b>`) are ignored. It shows plain text.

```
final String messageBody = "<b>Hello, Google!</b>";
final ShareCompat.IntentBuilder intentBuilder = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(fragment.getActivity())
        .setType("text/html")
        .setSubject("Subject")
        .setHtmlText(messageBody)
        .setChooserTitle("Choose e-mail application:");
fragment.startActivity(intentBuilder.createChooserIntent());
```

I tested with **Gmail** and **Mail.Ru** email clients.

It works for me only on **API 16/17**, but it doesn't work **API 19** and greater.

[image: Nexus 5 - KitKat 4.4]

Comment: I just tried with **Outlook** and it works. Seems like some email apps don't process HTML text correctly. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to achieve what you want for all mail clients.

As different email clients handle emails differently(they use different HTML preprocessors). They have to prepare the HTML to be converted into HTML that’s safe to show within their own email client’s HTML. This is a surprisingly difficult thing to do and most web-based email clients’ preprocessors will err on the side of being overly restrictive and removing anything with even the slightest potential to affect the layout of their email client.